# Printf in assembler doesn't print

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, disassembly

I have got a homework to hack program using buffer overflow ( with disassambling, program was written in C++, I haven't got the source code ). I have already managed it but I have a problem. I have to print some message on the screen, so I found out address of printf function, pushed address of "HACKED" and address of "%s" on the stack ( in this order ) and called that function. Called code passed well but nothing had been printed.

I have tried to simulate the environment like in other place in the program but there has to be something wrong. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong that I have no output, please? Thanks a lot

EDIT:

This program is running on Windows XP SP3 32b, written in C++, Intel asm

there is the "hack" code

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
0012F9A3    90              NOP                                      ;hack begins
0012F9A4    90              NOP
0012F9A5    90              NOP
0012F9A6    89E5            MOV EBP,ESP
0012F9A8    83EC 7F         SUB ESP,7F                               ;creating a place for working data
0012F9AB    83EC 7F         SUB ESP,7F
0012F9AE    31C0            XOR EAX,EAX
0012F9B0    50              PUSH EAX
0012F9B1    50              PUSH EAX
0012F9B2    50              PUSH EAX
0012F9B3    89E8            MOV EAX,EBP
0012F9B5    83E8 09         SUB EAX,9
0012F9B8    BA 1406EDFF     MOV EDX,FFED0614                            ;address to jump, it is negative because there mustn't be 00 bytes
0012F9BD    F7DA            NOT EDX
0012F9BF    FFE2            JMP EDX                                     ;I have to jump because there are some values overwritten by the program
0012F9C1    90              NOP
0012F9C2    0090 00000000   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],DL
0012F9C8    90              NOP
0012F9C9    90              NOP
0012F9CA    90              NOP
0012F9CB    90              NOP
0012F9CC    6C              INS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI],DX                 ; I/O command
0012F9CD    65:6E           OUTS DX,BYTE PTR GS:[ESI]                ; I/O command
0012F9CF    67:74 68        JE SHORT 0012FA3A                        ; Superfluous address size prefix
0012F9D2    2069 73         AND BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+73],CH
0012F9D5    203439          AND BYTE PTR DS:[EDI+ECX],DH
0012F9D8    34 2C           XOR AL,2C
0012F9DA    2066 69         AND BYTE PTR DS:[ESI+69],AH
0012F9DD    72 73           JB SHORT 0012FA52
0012F9DF    74 20           JE SHORT 0012FA01
0012F9E1    3120            XOR DWORD PTR DS:[EAX],ESP
0012F9E3    6C              INS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI],DX                 ; I/O command
0012F9E4    696E 65 7300909 IMUL EBP,DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+65],-6F6FFF8D
0012F9EB    90              NOP
0012F9EC    90              NOP
0012F9ED    90              NOP
0012F9EE    31DB            XOR EBX,EBX                             ; hack continues
0012F9F0    8818            MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],BL               ; writing 00 behind word "HACKED"
0012F9F2    83E8 06         SUB EAX,6
0012F9F5    50              PUSH EAX  ; address of "HACKED"
0012F9F6    B8 3B8CBEFF     MOV EAX,FFBE8C3B
0012F9FB    F7D0            NOT EAX
0012F9FD    50              PUSH EAX   ; address of "%s"
0012F9FE    B8 3897BFFF     MOV EAX,FFBF9738
0012FA03    F7D0            NOT EAX
0012FA05    FFD0            CALL EAX    ;address of printf
```

beginning of the program:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00403F40  /$  55            PUSH EBP
00403F41  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
00403F43  |.  6A FF         PUSH -1
00403F45  |.  68 AB6D4100   PUSH pop3.00416DAB
00403F4A  |.  64:A1 0000000 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[0]
00403F50  |.  50            PUSH EAX
00403F51  |.  64:8925 00000 MOV DWORD PTR FS:[0],ESP
00403F58  |.  81EC 4C050000 SUB ESP,54C
00403F5E  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                                   ; /Arg1 = 0
00403F60  |.  E8 6BDEFFFF   CALL 00401DD0                            ; \pop3.00401DD0
00403F65  |.  83C4 04       ADD ESP,4
00403F68  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; /Arg1
00403F69  |.  E8 DA2D0000   CALL 00406D48                            ; \pop3.00406D48
00403F6E  |.  83C4 04       ADD ESP,4
00403F71  |.  837D 08 02    CMP DWORD PTR SS:[ARG.1],2
00403F75  |.  74 21         JE SHORT 00403F98
00403F77  |.  837D 08 03    CMP DWORD PTR SS:[ARG.1],3
00403F7B  |.  74 1B         JE SHORT 00403F98
00403F7D  |.  8B45 0C       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ARG.2]
00403F80  |.  8B08          MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
00403F82  |.  51            PUSH ECX
00403F83  |.  68 287D4100   PUSH OFFSET pop3.00417D28                ; ASCII "%s arg: port [log dir]"
00403F88  |.  E8 3A290000   CALL 004068C7                            ; this is probably address of printf, I have source code of previous version of this program, this part is probably same
```

This code is really ugly because I am new in assembler and there mustn't be null bytes because of buffer-overflow bug

Comment: Wow. I wish we had such homework assignments.

Comment: You need to post your code if you want people here on SO to help you debug it.

Comment: @Paul R: Code is simple, for calling of this function I am using 3 instructions: 2x PUSH a 1x CALL. Other values ( registers and rest of stack ) are not defined, it could be whatever. Values of PUSHes and CALL are only addresses which are depended on the program but they are correct, that I checked many times. I think that problem is in some undefined value which I forgot to set, like some register etc.

Comment: @Gaim: without being able to see the code it's all just pointless speculation - is there some reason why you can't post the source ?

Comment: @Paul R: The only reason is that the program is quite big ( 40kB ) and specifying where the bug ( buffer-overflow ) is could be really difficult ( it is pop-server so you have to use telnet or something like this, the bug is only sometimes etc. ). I can post my "hack" code but I think that it is not interesting without program to hack.

Comment: Why don't you just trace through the printf call with a debugger?

Comment: @Gaim: you don't need to post all the code - just the part where you are trying to call printf. Oh, and you *really* need to specify what OS etc you are talking about here.

Comment: @chrisharris: I have tried but I am new in assembler so I might have overlooked it. But all values in registers and stack seemed to be correct. But no string had been printed.

Comment: @Paul R: Ok, I have edited my question. Is it better now or something is missing?

Comment: @Gaim: Better, but you still haven't stated what OS this is for, or what programming environment you're using. And where did the address of _printf come from ?

Comment: @Paul R: Ok, I have fixed it.

Comment: @Gaim: You really need to take the code here, edit it as a piece of ASM source complete with labels showing execution jumps and placement of literal data. The disassembly above is mis-leading as explained in my answer below. Personally in assembler, I also tend to annotate most lines, and indicate how parameters are passed at call entry points. Probably a result of too many unforgiving crashes in times past ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the mistake but I have changed structure of my hack code and now it is working. I am posting only few instructions which redirect EIP out of the stack to the heap where I have "unlimited" space and here I can execute desired code. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you that parameters to printf are passed in the right order, you have the right number of them, and they are all passed through the stack (optimization may mean registers are used instead).  The variable number of parameters could result in a more complex parameter list than your assuming.  Maybe try a call to **puts** which could be simpler.

**Edit:** Just saw your edit, and you're trying to disassemble a bunch of text that should never get executed;  The code starting as

```
0012F9CC    6C              INS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI],DX                 ; I/O command 
0012F9CD    65:6E           OUTS DX,BYTE PTR GS:[ESI]                ; I/O command 
0012F9CF    67:74 68        JE SHORT 0012FA3A                        ; Superfluous address size prefix 
0012F9D2    2069 73         AND BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+73],CH 
0012F9D5    203439          AND BYTE PTR DS:[EDI+ECX],DH 
0012F9D8    34 2C           XOR AL,2C
```

is actually just a piece of text saying 'ength is 494,first 1 lines'.  I spotted this as **printf** should not have INS and OUTS.  Hint: When hacking and disassembling code always look at it side by side in an editor that shows ASCII and UNICODE to root out text literals.

Comment: No, I am not trying to dissasamble text. This hack is part of stack ( buffer-overflow bug ) where i saved my "data". This text is written into the memory after I sent my hackcode and because of it there is jump at 0012F9BF.

Comment: So why manually annotate it with 'I/O command' etc...?  To me this clearly suggests executable code rather than data, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: it is not my annotation. This program has been compiled with -g so there are debug information. this hackcode is absolutely without comments by me, these ones which gives a sense are written only here because of reading and part of data which you mentioned is written by program few instructions latter after my hackcode.